# Update country field in MySQL table from GeoIP country database

Tags: mysql

I have a table which records IP addresses of my visitors. This table is named **crm_record**

I have downloaded the Maxmind GeoIP country database and want to update the country field in crm_record from this table

I know of this query to query the maxmind database

```
SELECT country_name
FROM crm_geo_country
WHERE INET_ATON("82.145.208.23") BETWEEN beginip AND endip
```

However I need the syntax for an UPDATE query which would allow me to update the country field on crm_record from crm_geo_country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  crm_record r
JOIN    crm_geo_country gc
ON      INET_ATON(r.address) BETWEEN gc.beginip AND gc.endip
SET     r.country = gc.country_name
```

Note that this is going to be quite inefficient.

You need either to store your IP addresses in numeric format of modify the geoip table to use spatial fields for storing ranges.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a fast answer! I see what you mean about the efficiency. Would I need to store them in numerical format in both tables?

Comment: @Michael: yes and create an index on `crm_record.address`. However, `crm_geo_country` will always be leading in the query which is not good since it's quite large. Consider storing the ranges in `crm_geo_country` as `LineString` instead. See here for details: http://explainextended.com/2009/04/04/banning-ips/

Comment: @Michael: yes I do, please contact me through http://explainextended.com/drop-me-a-line/

Comment: Just a quick update on this. I ended up using spatial indexes as per the recommended process in this URL http://jcole.us/blog/archives/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/ and this proved to be a far more efficient method. Thanks again

Comment: I have another related question here if you wouldn't mind having a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774365/mysql-csv-import-cannot-get-geometry-object-from-data-you-send-to-the-geometry